# WordPress comments allowed tags display

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to know how `allowed_tags()` function work and why it is not documented on wordpress.org page. Is this function deprecated or what? And is it good idea to use it to show tags users can use in comment?...

Answer (score 1):

```
function allowed_tags() {
    global $allowedtags;
    $allowed = '';
    foreach ( (array) $allowedtags as $tag => $attributes ) {
        $allowed .= '<'.$tag;
        if ( 0 < count($attributes) ) {
            foreach ( $attributes as $attribute => $limits ) {
                $allowed .= ' '.$attribute.'=""';
            }
        }
        $allowed .= '> ';
    }
    return htmlentities($allowed);
}
```